# How to config Laravel API and NuxtJS in same domain

Tags: laravel, nginx, nuxt.js

I have a domain like `domain.com`

I have a Web API (Laravel) at `domain.com/api`

I have landing page (Laravel) at `domain.com/`

I have blog (Laravel) at `domain.com/blog`

I have Web App (NuxtJS) at `app.domain.com`

I want to merge domain.com and app.domain.com into one. What do I have to do to achieve that?

My server uses Nginx and Centos 7. Thank you so much for reading my question!